# Working with json file newb

Tags: json

I haven't done really any work before using JSON files. I am wondering if anyone would be willing to help me out with this problem I have.

I host a game server for the game RUST and I am running a plugin that outputs all current players to a JSON file that I can access via FTP. 
This is an example of the file when 2 people are connected.

```
{
  "Online": {
    "Count": 2,
    "Players": {
      "76561197987660961": "-GunnRunner-",
      "76561198139941699": "Danjo1313"
    }
  }
}
```

I have been trying to find a way to take this information and put it into a nice format to show on a WordPress site. Normally i would use a service like GameTracker however this game currently doesn't support the current players feature on any of these services.

I would like to learn how to do this just not sure where to even begin.

Comment: Wordpress may have a plugin that you could potentially use to display your data. Pick one that supports JSON data (eg. tablePress).

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript.

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, and works really well with Javascript. Simply write a piece of code that gets the file from the website and javascript will do all the parsing for you. For example, if you download the file and put the content into the variable "a", to show the number of online players simply access "a.online.count".

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$json = '{
    "Online": {
        "Count": 2,
        "Players": {
           "76561197987660961": "-GunnRunner-",
           "76561198139941699": "Danjo1313"
        }
    }
}';

$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo "Players Online: ".$json['Online']["Count"]."\n";
foreach($json['Online']['Players'] as $id => $player){
    echo "Player: ". $player."\n";  
    echo "Player ID: ". $id."\n";   
    echo "============================================\n";  
}
```

This will output

```
Players Online: 2
Player: -GunnRunner-
Player ID: 76561197987660961
============================================
Player: Danjo1313
Player ID: 76561198139941699
============================================
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/SCKkei)**

**EDIT**

*as per your comment*

if you want to access the `json` from other server, one way is that you're using plugin,

the other way it could be to access resources using `php`

```
$json = file_get_contents("url.to/your/json/file");
```

in this way you'll get the `JSON`(mentioned above) in an variable `$json` and do the same as above on your website to display information.

**To show downward**

```
echo "Players Online: ".$json['Online']["Count"]."<br />";
```

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for! however i need to be able to get that output on a website and the json file is on a different ftp server

Comment: ok so essentially it would be     in a .php file?                                                                                 $json = file_get_contents("url.to/your/json/file");                                     $json = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo "Players Online: ".$json['Online']["Count"]."\n";
foreach($json['Online']['Players'] as $id => $player){
    echo "Player: ". $player."\n";  
    echo "Player ID: ". $id."\n";   
    echo "============================================\n";  
}

Comment: Ok so now i am having another issue and cant find exactly how to do it. the url is an ftp:// address and requires username and password. In my researching however ive seen ways to send the .json data to another server. so i am wondering if there is a way to send the .json file from the game server to my web server then use the above code to decode it? IDK just trying to come up with ideas :) Thank you so much for all the help

Comment: I can do ftp://username:password@url but is there a way to encrypt this?

Comment: "Players Online: 1 Player: bullet ===========================" is the current output what do i need to get it to list downward? not just across

Comment: instead of `\n` place `PHP_EOL` or `<br />` Updated my answer